# How to set page title for Edit and New in Active Admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using Active Admin in my project. I want to set the title of Edit and new action?
I have tried following but It wont change the title.

```
controller do
  def edit
    @page_title="This is Edit"
  end

  def new
    @page_title="This is New"
  end
end
```

and I also tried

```
member_action :edit do
  @page_title="This is Edit"
end

member_action :new do
  @page_title="This is New"
end
```

I am unable to set the title using above. 
How do i set the title?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Active Admin are you using? I'm using the latest code from GitHub, and these work just fine: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Set-page-title

Comment: @seanlinsley I am using Active Admin Version (0.6.0)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is already given in the solved issues of activeadmin gem, so you can also refer that
[Check Here](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/pull/2196)

Code:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
  form :title => { :new => "New Category", :edit => "Renew  Category"} do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :name
      f.input :description
    end
    f.actions do
      f.action :submit
      f.action :cancel, :label => 'Cancel', :input_html => {:class => 'cancel_subscription'}
    end
  end
end
```

Edit and New Forms shows the new titles ("Renew Category" and "New Category" respectively)

Hope this will help.
Thanks.

Comment: That was never actually merged into Active Admin.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade to 0.6.1 or above and you'll be good :)